# ruby heroku systemtimer issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gemfile

I'm trying to upload my rails project to heroku. I keep getting the error:

```
An error occurred while installing SystemTimer (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
```

I've done some research and made modifications accordingly, but it's still not working. First I tried commenting out SystemTimer in my gemfile, but that did't do it. My heroku system stack is apparently Cedar 1.9.1. My ruby version is 1.8.7. According to some research online, putting:

```
ruby '1.8.7'
```

in the gemfile would revert to Cedar 1.8.7, and compile it accordingly, but that didn't work either. Any idea what I could do? Here's the whole message I keep getting (not sure why 1.9.1 comes up, even though I've explicitly said 1.8.7 in my gemfile):

```
    Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
christophecompaq@ubuntu:~/Populisto-heroku$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 1347, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (871/871), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1347/1347), 3.09 MiB | 99 KiB/s, done.
Total 1347 (delta 426), reused 1033 (delta 276)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (0.9.5)
       Installing SystemTimer (1.2.3)
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       creating Makefile
       make
       gcc -I. -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -o system_timer_native.o -c system_timer_native.c
       In file included from system_timer_native.c:8:
       /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/rubysig.h:14:2: warning: #warning rubysig.h is obsolete
       system_timer_native.c: In function ‘install_first_timer_and_save_original_configuration’:
       system_timer_native.c:46: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:53: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:38: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:57: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:62: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:65: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:38: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:69: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:82: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:38: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:89: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:96: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:38: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:101: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c: In function ‘install_next_timer’:
       system_timer_native.c:112: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:119: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:38: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:123: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:130: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:38: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:136: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:143: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:38: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:146: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c: In function ‘restore_original_configuration’:
       system_timer_native.c:157: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:38: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:160: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:168: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:38: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:170: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:172: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:38: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c: In function ‘restore_original_timer_interval’:
       system_timer_native.c:190: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_error’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:38: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:192: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c: In function ‘restore_sigalrm_mask’:
       system_timer_native.c:199: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:201: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:37: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c: In function ‘install_ruby_sigalrm_handler’:
       system_timer_native.c:211: error: ‘rb_thread_critical’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       system_timer_native.c:211: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
       system_timer_native.c:211: error: for each function it appears in.)
       system_timer_native.c: In function ‘restore_original_ruby_sigalrm_handler’:
       system_timer_native.c:217: error: ‘rb_thread_critical’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       system_timer_native.c: In function ‘clear_pending_sigalrm_for_ruby_threads’:
       system_timer_native.c:266: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:237: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c: In function ‘set_itimerval’:
       system_timer_native.c:290: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:237: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       system_timer_native.c:299: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘log_debug’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
       system_timer_native.c:237: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
       make: *** [system_timer_native.o] Error 1
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_nn5uo1y1yyxf/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/SystemTimer-1.2.3 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_nn5uo1y1yyxf/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/SystemTimer-1.2.3/ext/system_timer/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing SystemTimer (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot
       continue.
       Make sure that `gem install SystemTimer -v '1.2.3'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer following links :

[Bundler error when pushing to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070035/bundler-error-when-pushing-to-heroku)

[Ruby on Rails - can not install SystemTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126336/ruby-on-rails-can-not-install-systemtimer)

How to install SystemTimer on 1.9.2 :

[How to install SystemTimer on 1.9.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850216/how-to-install-systemtimer-on-1-9-2)

Answer (score 0):

Try once `heroku restart`. You can also use timeout library from ruby 1.9 as an alternative of SystemTimer.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed.The problem seemed to be that, after my changes, I never pushed my project up to github. I'm getting a different error now, but it's not related to the System Timer. Thanks for your help!